# Partitioning query is full table scan or partition range

Tags: oracle, partitioning

Created a table with daily partitioning. 
In the select condition I am using the column used for daily partitioning(for getting two days data till now)

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE CREATED_TIME > TRUNC (sysdate -1)
```

But will this query go for full table scan or will it only scan fixed partitions?

In the explain plan I see the following

```
SELECT STATEMENT
|----PARTITION RANGE (ITERATOR)
|-------HASH (UNIQUE)
|------------TABLE ACCESS (FULL)
```

Doe this table access full means full table scan or full scan in partition?

Answer (score 2):

It means it will scan the partition. (It could be one or more partitions.)

Look for *"Viewing Partitioned Objects with EXPLAIN PLAN"* in [Database SQL Tuning Guide: Reading Execution Plans](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_interp.htm#TGSQL94720).